# Compare incoming message from ESP8266

Tags: esp8266

If there's one thing I never managed to do: it's comparing strings. 
So I have the incoming message saved here

```
String Message2 = IClient[i].readStringUntil('\n');
```

And every time I try to compare it with

```
strcmp(Message2.c_str(),"Red"); //Hopefully comparing the Message2 with "Red"
```

I never get 0 returned.

I know from printing the Message2 to Serial that Message2 contains the word "Red".

I've tried using different methods (`string.equal(string2);` etc.) but it never said that they are equal. What am I missing out on?

Comment: Might want to remove the extra characters ("..."). Or compare with "\"Red\"".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer!

After testing around with changing the terminator of the `readStringUntil('\n')` method it appears that there were leading and trailing white spaces, though not being displayed on the serial monitor they still had an impact on the `strcmp(string1, string2)` method.

I could solve this problem by "trimming" the received string before comparing it by using the `String1.trim();` method.

In the end looking like:

```
String Message2 = IClient[i].readStringUntil('\n');

Message2.trim();

strcmp(Message2.c_str(),"Red");
```

Comment: a week ago https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/62546/wifi-connection-times-out-if-credentials-retrieved-via-serial-terminal#comment134274_62546